# Supplying parameters to a Linux binary while running it from QtProcess

Tags: c++, linux, qt, ubuntu

The standard way to use Qprocess is as follows:

```
 QObject *parent;
 ...
 QString program = "./path/to/Qt/examples/widgets/analogclock";
 QStringList arguments;
 arguments << "-style" << "motif";

 QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess(parent);
 myProcess->start(program, arguments);
```

However, What I am trying to do is running the binary on the console (sh) and then copying the output from there to the textbox in Qt.

So now what I need to do in `myProcess->start(program, arguments);` is to pass `sh` in program and the binary name in `arguments`. But what if my binary takes commandline arguments too ? Where do i supply it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`arguments()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#arguments) :

```
#include <QApplication>

...

QStringList myArgs = qApp->arguments();

myProcess->start(program, myArgs);
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

/home/user/1.sh

```
#!/bin/sh

echo $1 >> /home/user/1.out
echo $2 >> /home/user/1.out
echo $3 >> /home/user/1.out
```

main.cpp

```
#include <QtCore>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    QString program = "sh";
    QStringList args;
    args << "/home/user/1.sh" << "qwe" << "123" << "c c c";

    QProcess p;
    p.start(program, args);
    p.waitForFinished();

    return 0;
}
```

After running my app, I got:

1.out

```
qwe
123
c c c
```

Seems working for me.